# PDF Text Object: what font and decoding should be used if there is no *Tf* operator?

Tags: parsing, pdf, fonts, adobe, decoding

What font and encoding should be used to decode and display a string inside BT/ET block, when there is no preceding *Tf* operator?

Would it be ok to replace such strings with empty ones?

For example:

```
BT
8.04 0 0 8.04 63 67.92 Tm
[(oL)-1 (Om)]TJ
...
...
ET
```

Refer to an Adobe specification or recommendation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the current text font is a text state parameter and, therefore, part of the graphics state.

Thus, to determine the current text font for some text in a text object it does not suffice to look for a **Tf** operation only inside that text object. The text font may have been set much earlier in the content stream, either inside a previous text object or at page description level. Furthermore, it may have been subject to previous save-graphics-state and restore-graphics-state operations.

But what if there really is no **Tf** operation at all before a text drawing operation? Well,

[image: ISO 32000-1, Table 105 - text state operators]

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 105 - text state operators)*

Thus, **there is no initial value for the text font**. So there also is no encoding known without a **Tf** operation.

Also earlier:

> To paint glyphs, a content stream shall first identify the font to be used. The **Tf** operator shall specify the name of a font resource.

*(ISO 32000-1, section 9.2.2 - Basics of Showing Text)*

Thus, text drawing operations without a preceding **Tf** are actually invalid!

Thus, a strict text extractor could even stop extracting text from the stream in question as it clearly is broken.

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha One word of warning, though, my answer draws only from the specification. PDF viewers on the other hand may have an initial font value; thus, documents with text without a preselected font may display properly in such viewers and copy&paste from them may return matching results. PDF viewers have a long history of fixing PDF errors under the hood. Thus, in spite of the above being true you may eventually have issues opened claiming "My PDF viewer does extract that text, why doesn't your code?"